# How do I scrape a webpage without element selectors?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get parking violation data from DC's Open Data portal into R using the rvest package. For a couple of reasons, I need to use the data from [this page -- you'll need to scroll below the input fields](https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/DCGIS_DATA/Violations_Parking_2022/MapServer/2/query?outFields=*&where=1%3D1).

However, the data is not organized in a table, and on top of that, the values themselves are not located within element selectors. Is it possible to pull the values from this table?

Thank you,

Robin

Comment: So this is a REST API rather than a web page,  the data are well structured with consistent names and always with a : between the variable name and value. Are you sure you can't get this as JSON?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JSON, but will give Rui's answer a try since they've laid it out so clearly!

Answer (score 2):

Those pages have links to pages with JSON data. The code below first extracts the links, then the JSON data and finally creates a data.frame with the common data elements.

I will only download JSON data from 10 pages, since there are 2000 links.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

pattern <- "/dcgis/rest/services/DCGIS_DATA/Violations_Parking_2022/MapServer/2/\\d+$"

pg <- read_html(url)

pg %>%
  html_elements("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  stringr::str_match(pattern) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  as.vector() %>% 
  paste0("https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov", ., "?f=pjson") -> links

length(links)
#[1] 2000
```

Now download the JSON data and create a data.frame.

```
parking_data <- lapply(links[1:10], \(ll) {
  tmp <- fromJSON(ll)
  tmp$feature$attributes %>% unlist() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
})

common_cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(parking_data, names))
tickets_list <- lapply(parking, `[`, common_cols)
tickets <- do.call(rbind, tickets_list)
```

Comment: Thank you Rui! I haven't used JSON much before but this seems very straightforward - I'll give it a try and update the thread :)